# what should I do with layout don't work when I change page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, layout

I have layout and use this in two page and when i change page layout don't  work
why this is happening?

Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
I use this code for pages

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

On the new page (a .cshtml file a.k.a a view in the MVC site architecture), make sure you have specified which layout you are using in an ASP.NET code block.

Such as:

```
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}
```

the @{} is important in the above code. Also, if you haven't renamed the layout, you should just be able to write it as I specified, instead of having to do Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";